# Detect filled information in a input text dynamically

Tags: jquery, html

I have 3 input text field, what I want is that when I type somthing in the first input, the second input detects what was typed in and this input is going to be hidden. The 3rd input will detect the filled information in the 2nd hidden input.

This is what I tried with no succeed:

```
<script >
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#1').bind('input',function(){
    var val1 = $('#1').val();
    $('#2').val(val1);
  });
});
</script>

<script >
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#2").on("input", function() {
    var val2 = $('#2').val();
    $('#3').val(val2);
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: HI, just to clarify something if I did get this wrong: You want to hide second input if some keyword is entered in first input and then hide third input if something is entered in second input?

Comment: no, the only input that is going to be ghidden is the second one, so ill type something in input 1 this text will be detected by input 2 and the text in input 2 in will be detected in input 3, like a sequence. from 1 to 2 and from 2 to 3.

Comment: Then you can attach events on inputs like $('#id_of_input').keyup(function(){ if($(this).val() == 'something') { $('#id_of_second_input').hide(); });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `input` event is fired on a **user input**. When changing the input's value dynamically, using `.val()`, the event is **not** fired... But you can trigger it using [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#1').bind('input', function() {
    var val1 = $('#1').val();
    $('#2').val(val1).trigger("input").hide();
  });

  $("#2").on("input", function() {
    var val2 = $('#2').val();
    $('#3').val(val2);
  });
});
```

```css
/* color for inputs... To make them obvious in this demo only */

[id='1']{
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
[id='2']{
  border: 2px solid red;
}
[id='3']{
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="1">
<input id="2">
<input id="3">
```